# How to trigger function after render template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, marionette

I am using `marionette` in my application. I am showing `ItemView` through `regions` like in the following.

```
var productInfoViewObj=new productInfoView.ProductInfoView({model:tagInformationModel.tagInformationModelObj});
exports.MyApp.bodyContainer.show(productInfoViewObj);
```

This is the code, I written inside `view`.

```
   exports.ProductInfoView=Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        domInfo:{
            mainTemplateId:"tagProductListTpl",
            tableTemplateId:"taginfoViewTpl",
            tableContentDiv:"taginfoViewDiv",
            //tad Info
            tagInfoTabId:"tagInfoBtn",
            productInfoTabId:"productInfoBtn"
        },
        template:function(){
            return commonFunctions.templateCompilation("tagProductListTpl","");
        },
        onRender:function(){
            console.log(document.getElementById("productInfoBtn"));
        }
    });
```

I am passing `templateId and data` as arguments to `commonFunctions.templateCompilation`. It will compile and return `compiled string`. That compiled result passing to `template`.

As per my assumption, after completion of `template`, `onRender` function will trigger. What I mean before `onRender`, dom will available whatever we are templating using `template`.

But I am getting `null` inside `onRender` function.

I want a callback, it should trigger after `template` available in dom. so I can access elements whatever I templated using `template`.

I can do one thing, whatever I written inside `onRender`, I can setup `time` like in the following way.

```
 onRender:function(){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(document.getElementById("productInfoBtn"));},1000);
 }
```

If I set `time`, working fine but it's not correct way to implement.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved, I have to use `onShow` instead of `onRender` function. Now it's working fine.